# Ubuntu Server MySQL - Can't access with root user

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I'm new to `Ubuntu Server` and I did the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

Everything goes fine and I'm taken back to the command line. When I type:

```
mysql -u root
```

I got an error saying `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. Any ideas what I did wrong? I have tried removing all 3 packages and reinstalling them to no avail. Google has proven no help :(

Comment: For sure, its password error, Ubuntu generally ask you admin password when you installing package, did it ask you password when you where installed mysql?  I guess you need to reset password of mysql root

Answer (score 6):

Open the terminal and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` give new password for mysql

`mysql -uroot -p` , give newly created password

Note: You may have to add mysql version in first command Eg: dpkg-reconfigure mysqlserver-4.3

Answer (score 4):

For newer versions of MySQL (for MariaDB < 10.2 use the query at the bottom as it doesn't support alter user but still uses auth_socket)

> If you install 5.7 and don’t provide a password to the `root` user, it
>   will use the `auth_socket` plugin. That plugin doesn’t care and
>   doesn’t need a password. It just checks if the user is connecting
>   using a UNIX socket and then compares the username.

Taken from [Change User Password in MySQL 5.7 With "plugin: auth_socket"](https://dzone.com/articles/change-user-password-in-mysql-57-with-plugin-auth) and https://askubuntu.com/a/801950/395418

So in order to to change the `plugin` back to `mysql_native_password`:

1. Login with sudo:

   ```
   sudo mysql -u root
   ```
2. Change the `plugin` and set a password with a single command:

   ```
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
   ```

Of course you can also use the command above to set an empty password.

Just for the record, there is also another way to only change the `plugin` without providing a password (leaving it empty):

```
    update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where User='root';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I spent 4 hours swearing at this problem, and this solution just worked on my fresh installation of ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql
```

Then you will be logged into mysql, type following:

```
use mysql;
update user set password='*6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4' where User='root';
flush privileges;
```

After this, stop mysql, and start is as ordinary

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/etc/init.d/mysql start
mysql -u root -p
```

Your password should be: **mypass**

Answer (score 1):

You need to set MySQL

```
$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

Comment: I've tried this. It gives me the same error message as the mysql login.

Comment: try this but with sudo: `$ sudo mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD`

Comment: Please recover your mysql password http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html

Answer (score 1):

Before you reset the password try this:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

After this you have to write your password (don't worry if you don't see any * this is normal) and press the return button.

Comment: I tried that. When I do it asks for a password and if I type something in it says the same access is denied error except (using password: YES)

Comment: Are you totally sure, that your password is correct? The password is case sensitiv...

Comment: I've only put it one password the whole time I've had my linux server running (which is like a week). I didn't have to set a password when mysql installed? Was I supposed to?

Comment: Try the command which I posted again but this time just press return after you should write your password.

Comment: After trying that I got "Can't connect to the local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Answer (score 1):

Tested on **mysql 5.7.12**

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

Then from opened sql console type the following commands:

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

Stop the current process and start it again.
Then test the new password (should be **MyNewPass**).

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/etc/init.d/mysql start
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a forgotten password you need to stop the mysql deamon, start it with the `--skip-grant-tables` option, then change the current password using `mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD`.

You can found a full password reset procedure [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html).